# A property of complex functions to be proven.

Tags: complex-analysis

If a holomorphic on the whole complex plane funtion $f$ has a bounded real part then it is constant.

Could I use here Cauchy-Riemann equations here? They seem to lead me nowhere.

Comment: "Holomorphic" by itself is meaningless.  Holomorphic on what set?  The function $f(z) = z$ is holomorphic on $\{z \in \Bbb{C} : -1 < \Re(z) < 1\}$, has bounded real part in that set, but is clearly not constant.

Comment: Thanks. I meant holomorphic on the whole complex plane.

Comment: The real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic function. Therefore, if a harmonic function is bounded [then...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville.27s_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f \in H(\Bbb{C}) &\wedge \Re(f) < M \in \Bbb{R}  \\
    &\implies \mathrm{e}^f \text{entire} \wedge|\mathrm{e}^f| < \mathrm{e}^M   \\
    &\underset{\text{Louisville }}\implies \exists c \in \Bbb{C} \smallsetminus \{0\}, \mathrm{e}^f = c  \\
    &\implies f = \ln c  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

> A very good way to get at bounded real or imaginary parts is to consider $|\mathrm{e}^f|$ and $|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}f}|$.